# Javascript Cannot read property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying get and set image src using javascript and i keep getting this error, uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null. I have search Stackoverflow and could not find a solution. Here is my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"></h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
  <img src="" id="modalImg">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

```
<script>
function viewProduct(product_id){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/view_product_details/?product_id=' + product_id, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('exampleModalLongTitle').innerHTML = data.name
        document.getElementById('modalBody').innerHTML = data.description
        //document.getElementById('modalImg').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)
        document.getElementById('modalImg').src = data.image_url
    }
}
request.send();
}
 </script>
```

Comment: What does console.log(this.responseText) look like?

Comment: You're overwriting the image element with `document.getElementById('modalBody').innerHTML`.

Comment: this document.getElementById('modalBody').innerHTML = data.description erases the innerHTML, thus <img src="" id="modalImg"> is removed

Comment: You can't select an element that doesn't exist. You can't get the src property of null.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('modalBody').innerHTML` is erasing the image element.

Instead of `innerHTML` try [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
document.getElementById('modalBody').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', data.description);
```

> 'afterbegin': Just inside the element, before its first child.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by removing `<img src="" id="modalImg">` inside the body of  `<div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
  <img src="" id="modalImg">
</div>` and putting it above the the

```
      <img src="" id="modalImg">
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
     </div>
```

Comment: This isn't a very good solution because it puts modal content outside the container that's specifically meant for the modal content.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using `vscode` `Live Server` extension to open simple html file, `Live Server` work in background with the error. I stop `Live Server` and simply open html file in browser, then no error show.